# Combining Joins

Tags: sql, join

My X table has the facility name, and manufacturer name, but I need to display them as facilityID and manufacturerID.

I wrote two joins to display them:

The first one dislays facility ID:

```
select T1.facilityID, t2.*
from lkuFacility t1 right join X t2 on t1.facilityName = t2.facility
and t1.siteCode = t2.siteID
order by siteid
```

The second one displays manufacturer ID:

```
select T1.manufacturerID, t2.*
from lkuManufacturer t1 right join X t2 on t1.manufacturerName = t2.manufacturer
order by manufacturerid
```

How can I put them into one query, to show both facility ID and manufacturer ID on one results screen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want them linked based on table `X`, try this:

```
SELECT f.facilityID, m.manufacturerID, X.*
FROM X
LEFT JOIN lkuFacility AS f
ON f.facilityname = X.facility AND f.siteCode = X.siteID
LEFT JOIN lkiManufacturer AS m
ON m.manufacturerName = X.manufacturer
```

**Edit:**
If you want to join them into the same result set but not side-by-side (as above), you should be able to use the `UNION` operator like so:

```
select T1.facilityID, t2.*
from lkuFacility t1 right join X t2 on t1.facilityName = t2.facility
and t1.siteCode = t2.siteID
UNION ALL
select T1.manufacturerID, t2.*
from lkuManufacturer t1 right join X t2 on t1.manufacturerName = t2.manufacturer
order by manufacturerid
```

Comment: for the second, i'm getting: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'.

Comment: @xrum: Sorry, forgot to remove the `ORDER BY`. You Can only have one `ORDER BY` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [UNION](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_%28SQL%29#UNION_operator) ALL operator to concatenate the two queries.

Comment: You should use UNION ALL in this case not UNION as the query sets are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind them on separate lines then do a UNION ALL statement. If you want both on the same line you may have to do two joins to the X table.

Comment: i need them to be two separate columns.

Comment: Then use @Drackir's solution.