# Combining SQL Server Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server and I have two tables and I would like to combine into one query that I can use to fill a gridview.

**Table1 dbo.Work**
UID         (PK, int)
Tech_Ticket     (int)
RMA_Ticket      (int)
Region      (nchar10)
Completed       (nchar10)
FA      (nchar10)
Agent       (nvarchar50)
Tracking        (nvarchar50)
Date_Added      (date)
Date_Updated    (date)

**Table2 dbo.Orders**
UID         (PK, int)
Order       (int)
Agent       (nvarchar50)
Ticket      (int)
Notes       (nvarchar50)

Right now I have them setup as two separate queries and two separate tables.

**Query1:**

```
SELECT [Agent], 
  SUM(CASE WHEN [Date_Added] BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'New ', 
  SUM(CASE WHEN [Date_Updated] BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Worked', 
  SUM(CASE WHEN [Completed] = 'yes' AND [Date_Updated] BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Completed', 
  SUM(CASE WHEN [Failure_Analysis] = 'yes' AND [Date_Updated] BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'FA' 
  FROM Work 
  GROUP BY [Agent]
```

**Query2:**

```
SELECT [Agent] 
  SUM(CASE WHEN [Date] BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Orders'
  FROM Orders 
  GROUP BY [Agent]
```

Is there a way to combine these two queries into one?

Comment: I suggest you have a look at Joins, they can combine multiple tables in a query together.

Comment: What is the common field between the two tables? (Agent?)

Comment: Please add T-SQL code for the tables to your question so that we can copy the code into a query window. Use markdown code formatting to get syntax highlighting as well.

Comment: Are work and orders related to each other?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combining Joins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648753/combining-joins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `JOIN` them. Assuming that `Work` is the main table, it should be like this:

```
SELECT A.*, B.Orders
FROM (  SELECT  [Agent],
                SUM(CASE WHEN [Date_Added] BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'New',
                SUM(CASE WHEN [Date_Updated] BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Worked',
                SUM(CASE WHEN [Completed] = 'yes' AND [Date_Updated] BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Completed',
                SUM(CASE WHEN [Failure_Analysis] = 'yes' AND [Date_Updated] BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'FA'
        FROM Work 
        GROUP BY [Agent]) A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   [Agent]
                    SUM(CASE WHEN [Date] BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Orders' 
            FROM Orders 
            GROUP BY [Agent]) B
ON A.[Agent] = B.[Agent]
```

Comment: @user1361180 - Glad it worked. If it answered your question correctly, please consider mark it as accepted (checking the mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green)