# Combining sql queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to T SQL, I have two query's that I need to combine them according to common column value. 
Both query are working fine individually.

First query is

```
SELECT t_senderTable.nameFull AS "senderName", t_recieverTable.recieverName AS "recieverName" 
FROM ((dbo.t_senderTable AS t_senderTable
     INNER JOIN t_senderTable AS t_senderTable ON (t_senderTable.Kd = mapTable.senderID))
     INNER JOIN t_recieverTable AS t_recieverTabler ON (recieverTable.Id = mapTable.recieverID )
```

Second query is

```
SELECT t_license AS "License", t_coName AS "Company Name" 
FROM (dbo.t_license AS t_license
     INNER JOIN dbo. t_coName ON ( t_coName.id = t_license.senderID ))
WHERE
(
  t_license.check < '2' )
```

Basically I need to combine the two query's, so that using senderID that is common between two query's I get output result of senderName, recieverName and coName
senderID is one to many relation. 
Was getting idea from this post but cant get it to work [Combining SQL Server Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351398/combining-sql-server-queries)
Any ideas how to go about it? Thanks

Comment: If you just add the senderID to the list of columns selected in both queries, then do a left join just like you found the link you posted, that should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the two queries as subqueries, include the senderId field in the select clause of both the subqueries and join on those values.  I think what you are asking for is:

```
SELECT q1.senderName
     , q1.recieverName
     , q2."Company Name"
(
SELECT t_senderTable.nameFull AS "senderName", t_recieverTable.recieverName AS "recieverName" 
     , t_senderTable.Id
FROM ((dbo.t_senderTable AS t_senderTable
     INNER JOIN t_senderTable AS t_senderTable ON (t_senderTable.Kd = mapTable.senderID))
     INNER JOIN t_recieverTable AS t_recieverTabler ON (recieverTable.Id = mapTable.recieverID )
) q1
INNER JOIN (
SELECT t_license AS "License", t_coName AS "Company Name" 
     , t_license.senderID
FROM (dbo.t_license AS t_license
     INNER JOIN dbo. t_coName ON ( t_coName.id = t_license.senderID ))
WHERE
(
  t_license.check < '2' )
) q2
  ON q1.Id = q2.senderId
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UNION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx)(removes duplicate rows) or [UNION ALL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx)(returns all rows). For it to work, your columns need to match in both queries.

Comment: @J.Davidson: Just a note for this - if you have any `TEXT` or `NTEXT` or similar large fields in your SQL you'll have to use `UNION ALL`.