# Joining queries in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have this query which gets

```
select top 20 
    Articulo.IdArticulo, 
    VentasT30 as VentasPorMes, 
    MovStockTotal.Stock 
from 
    VentasMensuales 
join 
    MovStockTotal on MovStockTotal.IdArticulo = Articulo.IdArticulo 
where 
    Mes = 12 and IdDeposito = 30 
order by 
    VentasT30 desc
```

Basically, it gets the the top selling articles in my database, their monthly sales (VentasT30, stores in the VentasMensuales table) and the amount of stock available to sell in any store (IdDeposito identifies the store in the MovStockTotal table, currently I am checking only for store #30).

The MovStockTotal table tallies current stock numbers for each article in each store, so each article would have one line for the stock at store (IdDeposito) #30, one for the stock at store #40 (so on) and one for the main supply depot, #2.

I want to also know the stock available in the main distribution hub for all my client's stores. This is stored in the same table (MovStockTotal) under IdDeposito=2.

I'm not sure how to do this. I tried joining them as

```
SELECT 
    A.*, B.Stock
FROM 
   (select top 20 
       Articulo.IdArticulo, IdSeccion as Seccion, 
       Descripcion, VentasT30 as VentasPorMes, 
       MovStockTotal.Stock 
    from 
       VsBoremix.dbo.VentasMensuales 
    join 
       VsBoremix.dbo.Articulo on articulo.IdArticulo = VentasMensuales.IdArticulo 
    join 
       VsBoremix.dbo.MovStockTotal on MovStockTotal.IdArticulo = Articulo.IdArticulo 
    where 
       Mes = 12 and IdSeccion = 101 and IdDeposito = 30 
    order by 
       VentasT30 desc
    GROUP BY [IdArticulo]) A
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT   
        [IdArticulo] Stock 
     where 
        IdDeposito = 2 as StockT20
     FROM 
        VsBoremix.dbo.MovStockTotal
     GROUP BY 
        [IdArticulo]) B ON A.[IdArticulo] = B.[IdArticulo]
```

I copied the structure to that from another similar question I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351398/combining-sql-server-queries) but I'm really not quite sure what I'm doing or what to change there to make it work...

Specifically, the errors are

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'.
>   Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

In case it's not clear, the first query, which already works, returns

```
IdArticulo    VentasPorMes    Stock
03-00043           53          12
03-00044           25          5
03-00049           41          22
```

I want it to show

```
IdArticulo    VentasPorMes    Stock    StockT20
03-00043           53          12         30
03-00044           25          5          25
03-00049           41          22         40
```

Comment: `SELECT   [IdArticulo]
                Stock where IdDeposito=2 as StockT20
        FROM VsBoremix.dbo.MovStockTotal
        GROUP BY [IdArticulo]` is not formated correctly.  where caluse is before the from.  Proper syntax is Select, FROM, WHERE, GROUP BY, HAVING.  With all of the sub selects, performance may become a problem over time.  There's likely a better way to build this.

Answer (score 0):

CORRECTIONS APPLIED:

1. moved from so it's before where on left join sub table.
2. removed as StockT20 on where clause in left join sub table. ( you can't alias a where clause)

Issues: I've not addressed performance issues that may exist.  I've not looked to see if there were other issues beyond that of the syntax errors.
.

```
SELECT A.*, B.Stock 
FROM 
  (SELECT top 20 Articulo.IdArticulo, IdSeccion as Seccion, 
    Descripcion, VentasT30 as VentasPorMes, MovStockTotal.Stock 
   FROM VsBoremix.dbo.VentasMensuales 
   INNER JOIN VsBoremix.dbo.Articulo 
     on articulo.IdArticulo = VentasMensuales.IdArticulo 
   INNER JOIN VsBoremix.dbo.MovStockTotal 
     on MovStockTotal.IdArticulo = Articulo.IdArticulo 
   WHERE Mes = 12 
     and IdSeccion = 101 
     and IdDeposito = 30 
   ORDER BY VentasT30 desc
   GROUP BY [IdArticulo]) A
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT [IdArticulo] as Stock 
   FROM VsBoremix.dbo.MovStockTotal
   WHERE IdDeposito = 2  
   GROUP BY [IdArticulo]) B 
     ON A.[IdArticulo] = B.[IdArticulo]
```